# How to delete all vertices that have no edges in igraph python?

Tags: python, igraph

I have a graph with a lot of vertices without edges.

```
IGRAPH UN-- 560 49 -- 
+ attr: area (v), cnpj (v), grande_area (v), name (v), res (v), std (v), company (e), res (e), std (e)
```

I would like to delete all vertices that have no edges...
Something like:

```
 to_delete_ids = [v.index for v in g_groups_all.vs if v HAS NO EDGES]
 g_groups_all.delete_vertices(to_delete_ids)
```

But I don't know how to write the conditional to check if the vertex has no edges. I tried `v._source == None or v._target != True` with no success.

My edges `e['company'] e['res'] and e['std']` can be `True` or `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embarrassed to have asked such a question. Of course...

```
 to_delete_ids = [v.index for v in g_groups_all.vs if v.degree() == 0]
 g_groups_all.delete_vertices(to_delete_ids)
```

Obviously! 
But it took me some time to come up with that...

Comment: A more compact alternative: `g_groups_all.vs.select(_degree=0).delete()`